# Job information in careers profile is not displayed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

My profile page says:

> You might also wish to indicate full-time vs part-time, telecommute, or willingness to relocate.

I have indicated that I'd like to telecommute, and when I click "edit" it is checked, but after saving it's the same "you might.." message again.

In addition, the telecommuting preference doesn't show in the employer view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That text is just the help text for the section, so you know what you can put there when you click the Edit link. So if you change your mind in the future, you know where to go to update your status.

Telecommuting preference shows up in the employer view as "Open to working remotely".